# Is there a way to check whether the argument passed into a function is an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

```
const validateCred = arr => {
    let checkableArr = arr.pop();
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr[i]
        checkableArr.push(arr[i])
    }

}
```

When i run the code, I get an error saying that `.push()` is not a function that I can use on `checkableArr`. this is because `checkableArr` isn't an array due to it being a variation of `arr` (the argument that will be passed when the function is called), which the function isn't sure is an array, is there any way to check that the argument passed into the function is an array?

**EDIT:**

The thing I was looking for is called `isArray()`, a method that returns a boolean indicating if the item passed into it is an array or no. Thanks to @David for showing me this tool, along with a bunch of helpful information that helped a lot with writing my program

Comment: `pop` returns the last element and not an array. What are you trying to do in the function? If you are trying to reverse the array, then `let checkableArr = []` and `return checkableArr` outside the `for` loop

Comment: @hungerstar I'm pretty sure that your suggestion will fail as well, because `.pop` alters the array, which means your `checkableArr` will contain the value _right before the last item_ (which has already been removed) :-) I'm sure you meant `let item = arr.pop(); let checkableArr = Array.isArray(item) ? item : [];`

Comment: @David yes, thanks for catching that. Calling `.pop()` on `arr` twice like that would remove the last item twice and provided the wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error, because you haven't made sure that the *last* item of the passed array (`arr`) is an array itself, but your function's logic *requires* it to be an array.

There are various ways to solve this, some of them have already been outlined by others (@hungerstar).

**Check the last element of `arr`**

One attempt is to ensure that the last element/item inside `arr` is an array and bail out if it isn't.

```
const validateCred = arr => {
  let lastItem = arr.pop();
  if (!Array.isArray(lastItem)) {
    throw new Error('validateCred :: Last item of passed array must be an array itself');
  }
  // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

Although that does not solve the root cause, it ensures you get a decent and descriptive message about what went wrong. It's possible to *improve* that by defining a *fallback array* in case the last item isn't an array itself. Something like this:

```
const validateCred = arr => {
  let lastItem = arr.pop();
  let checkableArr = Array.isArray(lastItem) ? lastItem : [];
  // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

One thing to note: If the last item *may be an array with a value inside*, you have to copy that value into the new array!

```
const validateCred = arr => {
  let lastItem = arr.pop();
  let checkableArr = Array.isArray(lastItem) ? lastItem : [lastItem]; // <--
  // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

*HINT: The following answer is based on guessing. The name `validateCred` lets me assume you use it to validate credentials. However, that's just guessing because all the provided code does is taking the last item and then pushing the rest of the contents of `arr` reversely into it (= reversing and flattening)*

**Reversing and flattening**

If all you want to do with `validateCred` is reversing and flattening (and you only target supporting environments), you can easily do that with a one-liner:

```
// impure version
const validateCred = arr => arr.reverse().flat();

// pure version
const validateCred = arr => arr.flat().reverse();
```

To support older environments as well, you can use `.reduce` and `.concat` instead of `.flat`:

```
// impure version
const validateCred = arr => arr.reverse().reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x), []);

// pure version
const validateCred = arr => arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x), []).reverse();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we pass an array as an argument using call/apply method.  In your code when you are using `arr.pop()` it gets converted to number/string depending upon what type of array you specified, I specified below integer value so `checkableArr` is now integer so because of this you are getting an error.

Corrected code is here. Just replace in your code like:

```
let checkableArr = arr; //arr.pop();
```

Comment: `array.prototype.pop` does _not_ convert values into `String` or `Number` (or anything else), it merely returns _the last element inside the array_. Also, your "fix" will produce a different result: If we give `[1, 2, []]` to the given code, it results in `[2, 1]`. Your change will make it produce `[1, 2, [], [] 2, 1]`.